# Delphi: How to pass a object and class as parameter in this procedure (TMS Aurelius)?

Tags: delphi, orm, procedure, rtti, tms

I have a procedure in my class UserController to delete an object of class TUser based on their ID. I am wanting to make a GenericController class to be able to do this with any other class. This is my procedure:

```
procedure TUserController.DeleteUser(User: TUser);
begin
  if not FManager.IsAttached(User) then
    User := FManager.Find<TUser>(User.ID);
  FManager.Remove(User);
end;
```

I tried doing this:

```
procedure TGenericController.Delete(Class_: TObject; Class_ID: Integer);
    begin
      if not FManager.IsAttached(Class_) then
        Class_ := FManager.Find<Tclass(Class_)>(Class_ID);
      FManager.Remove(Class_);
    end;
```

But I receive this error:

```
[dcc32 Error] GenericController.pas(36): E2531 Method 'Find' requires explicit type argument(s)
```

This the method Find from TMS Aurelius:

```
function TObjectManager.Find<E>(IdValue: Variant): E;
begin
  Result := E(Find(TClass(E), IdValue));
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are resolved at compile-time but `Tclass(Class_)` (which can be replaced with `Class_.ClassType` instead) is not known until run-time, so it cannot be used as a Generic parameter value.

**Update**: As SirRufo tried to explain in comments, you could do something more like this:

```
procedure TGenericController.Delete<E>(Obj: E; Obj_ID: Integer);
begin
  if not FManager.IsAttached(Obj) then
    Obj := FManager.Find<E>(Obj_ID);
  FManager.Remove(Obj);
end;
```

For instance, if `TUserController` derives from `TGenericController`, then `DeleteUser()` could do this:

```
procedure TUserController.DeleteUser(User: TUser);
begin
  inherited Delete<TUser>(User, User.ID);
end;
```

Comment: you recommend another way of doing this?

Comment: Use also generics for the method `procedure TGenericController.Delete<E>(IdValue: Variant); var LInst : E; ... LInst := FManager.Find<E>(IdValue); ...`

Comment: @SirRufo I did not get success, still the same error. Find needs a class type.

Comment: @Artur_Indio: in SirRufo's example, `Find()` would get its class type from the Generic parameter that you have to pass to `Delete()`.